# SQL filter out where rows match ALL criteria

Tags: sql-server, select, filter, where-clause

I have a table where I have to make a select statement.
The table contains 1,616,372 values, and I need to make sure that 5,177 of them are not displayed in the select statement based on certain filteres.

I have made a select statement which returns all the values I need to filter out:

```
SELECT  
[EntryNo] 
,[AccountNo] 
,[CompanyNo] 
,[Description] 
,[Date] 
,[Code] 
FROM dbo.Table 
WHERE CAST([Date] AS Time) = '23:59:59.0000000' 
AND [Code] <> 'x' 
AND YEAR([Date]) = 2020
```

This gives me the 5,177 rows I need to filter out.

But when I create a SELECT * FROM xxx and add the opposite WHERE clause of what you see here, it filters out rows that match ANY of the criteria and not ALL of the criteria.

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Table 
WHERE CAST([Date] AS Time) <> '23:59:59.0000000' 
AND [Code] <> 'x' 
AND YEAR([Date]) <> 2020
```

I've tried putting various parenthesis around the criteria, but I can't make it work, so that it only filters out the 5,177 rows.

The rows do not have any specific ID since they are in a staging table, and what makes them distinct is the combination of [EntryNo] and [CompanyNo].

I hope you can help.

Comment: `NOT (a AND b AND c) = (NOT a OR NOT b OR NOT c)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't negate the condition correctly in your second query, `and` should become `or` (according to [DeMorgan's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws))

Or, instead of doing it manually, you can wrap everything in a negation and let SQL do the work:

```sql
WHERE NOT(
    CAST([Date] AS Time) = '23:59:59.0000000' 
    AND [Code] <> 'x' 
    AND YEAR([Date]) = 2020
)
```